# clojure destructuring array into individual arguments

Tags: clojure

i am trying to do a multi insert using clojure.java.jdbc

the structure for multi-insert is something like this

```
(jdbc/multi-insert! db-spec :table_name 
  {:col1 "d1" :col2 "d2" :col3 "d3"}
  {:col1 "d4" :col2 "d5" :col3 "d6"}...)
```

however i have the data in a vector like this

```
[
      {:col1 "d1" :col2 "d2" :col3 "d3"}
      {:col1 "d4" :col2 "d5" :col3 "d6"}
]
```

how do i destructure the array and pass the contents as individual arguments ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) to call a function with a list of arguments.

```
> (str "Clo" "jure")
"Clojure"
> (apply str ["Clo" "jure"])
"Clojure"
```

In your case you want to apply `jdbc/multi-insert!` with a list containing `db-spec`, `:table_name` and all the maps from your existing vector.

```
(def data [{:col1 "d1" :col2 "d2" :col3 "d3"}
           {:col1 "d4" :col2 "d5" :col3 "d6"}])

(apply
  jdbc/multi-insert!
  (conj [db-spec :table_name] data))
```

We're just using [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) to create the argument list, then passing it to `apply`.

As Alex pointed out, the signature for `apply` actually allows you to pass inline arguments first, so long as the final argument is a list. You could rewrite that example without using `conj`.

```
(apply
  jdbc/multi-insert!
  db-spec :table_name data)
```

Comment: No need to conj into the arg list, `apply` is variadic and only the last argument to it is expanded as a list.